# ASP.NET MVC Config Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What exactly is this line in the config doing when it is using IIS7 Integrated mode?

```
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
     path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,
         Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Without this I get an error saying it cannot find the .axd when trying to run my site but with it my site works, what does it do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is necessary to work around an obscure issue when using IIS7 in integrated mode and extensionless URLs. It enables extensionless URLs to work. This issue will be fixed in the future and we'll be able to remove that line. For now, just ignore it and don't remove it. :)